# Woocommerce Dynamic Shipping issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'replace_billing_city_field');
function replace_billing_city_field() {
    $current_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    if ($current_country === 'NG') {
        $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
        $cities_file_url = $plugin_url . 'cities.json';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var billingFieldsContainer = $('form.checkout').find('#billing_country_field, #billing_state_field, #billing_city_field');
        var billingCountryField = billingFieldsContainer.find('select#billing_country');
        var billingStateField = billingFieldsContainer.find('select#billing_state');
        var billingCityField = billingFieldsContainer.find('input#billing_city');
        var billingCitySelectField = $('<select>', {
            'name': billingCityField.attr('name'),
            'id': billingCityField.attr('id'),
            'class': billingCityField.attr('class') 
        });
        function updateBillingCityField() {
            var selectedCountry = billingCountryField.val();
            var selectedState = billingStateField.val();
            if (selectedCountry === 'NG') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo esc_url($cities_file_url); ?>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var states_cities = data['NG'];
                        if (selectedState === '') {
                            billingCitySelectField.html('');
                            billingCityField.replaceWith(billingCitySelectField);
                            billingCityField = billingCitySelectField; // Update the reference to the new select field
                        } else if (states_cities.hasOwnProperty(selectedState)) {
                            var cities = states_cities[selectedState].cities;
                            var options = '';
                            for (var key in cities) {
                                if (cities.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + cities[key] + '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                            billingCitySelectField.html(options);
                            billingCityField.replaceWith(billingCitySelectField);
                            billingCityField = billingCitySelectField; // Update the reference to the new select field
                        } else {
                            billingCitySelectField.replaceWith(billingCityField);
                            billingCityField = billingFieldsContainer.find('input#billing_city'); // Update the reference to the input field
                        }
                        billingCityField.show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                billingCityField.val('').hide();   
            }
        }
        billingCountryField.on('change', function() {
           updateBillingCityField();       
        });
        billingFieldsContainer.on('change', 'select#billing_state', function() {
           updateBillingCityField();
        });
        updateBillingCityField();
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

this code works properly on my website checkout page when i switch between the states in nigeria and my custom cities dropdown field for the billing city,   but when i switch to a different country and back to nigeria, the old data for my cities remains constant while switching between the states in nigeria until i reload the page. pleae can anyone help?

```
{
  "NG": {
    "AB": {
      "name": "Abia",
      "cities": {
        "": "Select a city",
        "City 1": "City 1",
        "City 2": "City 2"
      }
    },
    "LA": {
      "name": "Lagos",
      "cities": {
        "": "Select a city",
        "Agege": "Agege",
        "Ajeromi-Ifelodun": "Ajeromi-Ifelodun"
      }
    },
    "AD": {
      "name": "Adamawa",
      "cities": {
        "": "Select a city",
        "Demsa": "Demsa",
        "Fufore": "Fufore",
        "Ganye": "Ganye",
        "Girei": "Girei",
        "Gombi": "Gombi",
        "Guyuk": "Guyuk",
        "Hong": "Hong",
        "Jada": "Jada",
        "Lamurde": "Lamurde",
        "Madagali": "Madagali",
        "Maiha": "Maiha",
        "Mayo-Belwa": "Mayo-Belwa",
        "Michika": "Michika",
        "Mubi-North": "Mubi-North",
        "Mubi-South": "Mubi-South",
        "Numan": "Numan",
        "Shelleng": "Shelleng",
        "Song": "Song",
        "Toungo": "Toungo",
        "Yola North": "Yola North",
        "Yola South": "Yola South"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

these are the cities

Comment: Please provide in your question all the related code, like your city dropdown for Nigeria, as actually your provided code is not testable.

Comment: i only have two codes the second is the json file for the cities